# Converting boolean to positive or negative sign in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In quite a few of my MySQL queries I have a piece of computation

```
(CAST(return_item as SIGNED)*2-1)
```

Essentially that piece of code converts `true => 1` and `false => -1`, and it works great!
What I don't like about it is its readability in the SQL statements.

Is there a cleaner way to write this statement making it clearer on its intent?

`return_item` is `BIT(1)` which represents a boolean value in the system.

Comment: Like an `IF` statement? `IF(!return_item, 1, -1)`

Comment: it's hard to think of a good use case for this... maybe it's a schema design problem?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Probably!  I didn't design it, but I get to work with what I've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make your intent clear, there is hardly a better way than using a conditional:

```
IF(return_item, 1, -1)
```

Comment: @Kick_Backus : Try it!

Answer (score 2):

The most standard SQL way to do this would be a `CASE` statement:

```
CASE return_item WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
```

This is pretty readable, and will run in and be familiar to users of other database products.

Since the type in question is usable as a boolean, this also works, but would be less portable (Postgres's `boolean` type would work, but MS SQL Server's `bit` would not):

```
CASE WHEN return_item THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(return_item=true, 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about `SELECT POWER(-1, 1-SIGN(return_item))` ?